# How to update value in realtime database in Firebase using JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is what my database looks like:

[image: firebase database]

My question is how to I decrement the value of FIELD11 i.e. "4" in my realtime database in Firebase using javascript, everytime I click on DECREMENT Button on my html page it should decrement this value and get updated in realtime database. Thank You

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section first on how to properly ask and format a good question. Please also add code (see help section on formatting) of your JavaSctipt and html files that are related to your problem. Otherwise it will be hard to give any help.

Comment: Please, do not use this link to a photo. If the link expires, your question will be no longer helpful for other people. Write it as code.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a Firebase transaction.

> When working with data that could be corrupted by concurrent modifications, such as incremental counters, you can use a transaction operation.

Example:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions